# Rendering ERB HTML from Rails to Angular, Angular trying to interpret as JSON

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

I have the snippet below that sends a custom HTTP request through `$resource`.  The endpoint it hits returns an HTML response from an ERB template in Rails.

JS/Angular:

```
Case
  .getTemplate({ id: $routeParams.id, template: $scope.template.name })
  .$promise
  .then(function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
```

My goal is to then use that HTML and put it into a textarea.  However, the result of logging the response to the console shows JSON like so:

```
{
  "1": "<",
  "2": "!",
  "3": "d",
  "4": "o",
  "5": "c"
}
```

The very first characters in the HTML response are `<!doctype html>`.  Angular is splitting up the HTML response, character by character into JSON with the key being an iterator and the value being each character.

How can I prevent it from doing this so I can reference `response` in the anonymous function and use the HTML returned from the API.

Edit:

```
function CaseService($resource, BASE) {
  return $resource(BASE + 'cases/:id', {
    id: '@id'
  }, {
    getTemplate: {
      method: 'POST',
      url: BASE + 'cases/:id/get_template',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'text/html'
      }
    }
  });
}

angular
  .module('MyModule')
  .factory('Case', CaseService);
```

Comment: Where is the `Case.getTemplate()` function defined? Can you show it?

Comment: Added the service, left out the other methods for brevity.

Comment: Looking at the response in Chrome's developer tools in the Network tab it's exactly what I want, however, when logging it to the console Angular is doing something with the response to convert it to JSON which is not what i want.

Comment: There's a typo in your `getTemplate` object under the `headers` property. A missing single-quote. I don't think that would be causing the problem, though. You might also want to use `$http` instead of `$resource`, since it doesn't look like you'll be using standard RESTful routes.

Comment: I typed this up right on SO so that wasn't there in my app.  The routes are RESTful, but as with any application, there are some extra, unconventional routes for unique responsibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting your responseType to an empty string, which may override the default setting of json, as per the [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#responseType)

```
function CaseService($resource, BASE) {
  return $resource(BASE + 'cases/:id', {
    id: '@id'
  }, {
    getTemplate: {
    method: 'POST',
    url: BASE + 'cases/:id/get_template',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'text/html'
    },
    responseType: ''  // This is the magic line
  }
 });
```

This is mentioned in the [$resource doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource)

Comment: Same response as mentioned in the OP.

Comment: I'm not sure what else you could do. Either use `$http` or consider wrapping your html in a json object, eg. `{html: '!<doctype...'}.`

Comment: I did wrap it in a JSON object in the API, but Rails (when doing this) converts the HTML to unicode characters.  I'm looking for a solution, not an alternative :S

Comment: Ended up using $http and it worked.  The answer doesn't work but the suggestion in your comment solved my problem.